# MySQL - Searching & Conaining word / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to search an element into two different column of a MySQL database. The first may match the searchedObject the second may contain it (the column contain text). I'm using PHP

The page return me an error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\wamp\www\v2\header.php on line 9
```

Here is my request

```
"SELECT * FROM corporate WHERE (columnA = " . $_GET["searchedObject"]) . " OR (columnTextedB LIKE '%" . $_GET["searchedObject"] . "%' )";
```

Any idea to save my night :o ?

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear on what you have done wrong...

```
$_GET["searchedObject"])
```

Move that `)`... into

```
") OR (columnTextedBLIKE '%"
```

PS. this code is very vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is a problem in your PHP:

```
"SELECT * FROM cim_corporate WHERE (columnA = " . $_GET["searchedObject"]) . " OR (columnTextedBLIKE '%" . $_GET["searchedObject"] . "%' )";
```

Note that you close a bracket that is never opened in PHP. Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM cim_corporate WHERE (columnA = " . $_GET["searchedObject"] . ") OR (columnTextedBLIKE '%" . $_GET["searchedObject"] . "%' )";
```

However please do not use `$_GET variables` directly in queries. A malicious user can then add all sorts of nasty stuff to your query.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, I will not use the $_GET directly, that was just for testing (i didn't knew where the error was comming from)I did what you said, and it give me now a new error : Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\v2\header.php on line 14

Comment: @John You haven't shown your code but there is plenty of results for this error on stack overflow. Your call to mysql_query has failed calling mysql_error will give you the error but this is likely because you need quotes around your values in the query.